# i3: Starting mpv from ranger on different workspace

Tags: i3, mpv

I would like to configure my i3wm and ranger file manager in such a way that when I choose a movie in ranger, it opens video in mpv on workspace 10 in fullscreen. The problem is that everything works fine without `--fs` (fullscreen option on mpv), but when I add the `--fs` flag, i3 doesn't move mpv to workspace 10 and it opens wherever ranger is.

In `.i3/config`:

```
assign [class="mpv"] $ws10
```

In `.config/ranger/rifle.conf`:

```
mime ^video|audio, has mpv, X, flag f = mpv --fs -- "$@"
```

Why is fullscreen so problematic? Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I applied your settings: `assign [class="mpv"] $ws10` and `mime ^video|audio, has mpv, X, flag f = mpv --fs -- "$@"`. When I open a video file in ranger, mpv opens video in fullscreen mode in ws10. Actually, your settings work well on my machine :)

Since `--fs` is the problem for you, I would suggest to remove `--fs` in `.config/ranger/rifle.conf`:
`mime ^video|audio, has mpv, X, flag f = mpv -- "$@"`

And then, use `fullscreen` mode from i3wm:

`assign [class="mpv"] $ws10
for_window [class="mpv"] fullscreen`

Hope this alternative could solve your problem.